# How to draw a polynomial curve in matplotlib python?

Tags: python, python-2.7, matplotlib, regression

I'm trying to draw a curve for regression fitting. The curve is for a higher degree polynomial ( 6 and above ).

```
fig=figure()
ax1=fig.add_axes((0.1,0.2,0.8,0.7))
ax1.set_title("Training data(blue) and fitting curve(red)")
ax1.set_xlabel('X-axis')
ax1.set_ylabel('Y-axis')

ax1.plot(x_train,y_train,'.',x_train,np.polyval(best_coef,x_train),'-r') 
show()
```

[This is the output of the given code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MZh9M.png)

I want it to be a smooth curve.

[something like this , with a continues red line , instead of discreet point of red](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7FFmR.png)

Comment: Were did `best_coef` come from??  Did you write this?

Comment: i've written a polyfit function which returns the coefficient of best degree polynomial that fits the data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you just need to sort `x_train` before plotting the fit results:

```
ax1.plot(x_train,y_train,'.', np.sort(x_train),np.polyval(best_coef,np.sort(x_train)),'-r')
```

The plot you included looks like the `x_train` values (and therefore also the fitted values) are in random order, but the plot routine does not connect the nearest points, but consecutive points in the arrays.